# MobX: получение данных в сторе из другого стора

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Использую вот такую конструкцию для стора и валидации форм: https://medium.com/@KozhukharenkoN/react-form-validation-with-mobx-8ce00233ae27

Есть стор формы:

```js
import { observable, action, computed } from 'mobx'
import FormStore from './FormStore'

import UserStore from 'stores/UserStore'

class SettingsFormStore extends FormStore {
  @observable
  form = {
    fields: {
      email: {
        value: UserStore.email,
        defaultValue: UserStore.email,
        error: null,
        rule: 'required|email'
      },
    },
    meta: {
      isValid: true,
      error: null,
    },
  }
}

export default new SettingsFormStore()
```

есть стор юзера:

```js
import { observable, action, computed } from 'mobx'

import * as UserAPI from 'api/UserAPI'

class UserStore {
  @observable id
  @observable email

  constructor() {
    this.load()
  }

  @action setValues(values) {
    this.id = values.id
    this.email = values.email
  }

  @action removeValues() {
    this.id = null
    this.email = null
  }

  load() {
    UserAPI.getMe()
      .then(result => {
        this.setValues(result.user)
      })
  }
}

export default new UserStore()
```

В компоненте формы получаю
const email = SettingsFormStore.form.fields.email.value

но email почему-то undefied, хотя UserStore.email хранит в себе значение...

Answer (score 2):

У вас `SettingsFormStore.form` зависит от `UserStore.email`. Такие зависимости делаются через вычислимые свойства. Связывать сторы через них - правильнее, чем через реакции, потому что для них выполняются некоторые дополнительные свойства, такие как гарантия порядка выполнения.

```
class SettingsFormStore extends FormStore {
  @observable
  form = {
    fields: {
      email: {
        get value() { return UserStore.email },
        get defaultValue() { return UserStore.email },
        error: null,
        rule: 'required|email'
      },
    },
    meta: {
      isValid: true,
      error: null,
    },
  }
}
```

Но при таком подходе у вас `value` всегда будет равно `defaultValue` - наверное, это не совсем то что вы думали. Возможно, вы планировали использовать `value` для текущего значения, введенного пользователем - а `defaultValue` для значения до редактирования.

В таком случае лучше выделить абстракцию поля формы а отдельный класс:

```
class FormField {
    @observable _value = null;
    @observable isModified = false;

    constructor(defaultValueAccessor) {
        this._defaultValueAccessor = defaultValueAccessor;
    }

    @computed
    get value() {
        if (this.isModified) 
            return this._value
        else
            return this._defaultValueAccessor()
    }

    set value(value) {
        this._value = value;
        this.isModified = true;
    }

    @action
    reset() {
        this._value = null;
        this.isModified = false;
    }
}

class SettingsFormStore extends FormStore {
  @observable
  form = {
    fields: {
      email: new FormField(() => UserStore.email),
    },
    meta: {
      isValid: true,
      error: null,
    },
  }
}
```

Идея MobX - именно в построении подобной иерархии зависимых моделей.

Comment: А где в этой конструкции "error" и "rule" ?

Comment: @Max ну, я надеюсь, вы сами сможете их туда добавить.

Comment: что то не очень ясно...

Comment: @Max а что не ясно-то? Не ясно как добавить  еще одно @observable-свойство?

Comment: вопрос скорей куда? в объект form или в FormField ?

Comment: @Max зависит от того, где они вам нужны.

Answer (score -1):

Нашел решение:

```
constructor() {
    super()

    reaction(
      () => UserStore.email,
      email => {
        this.form.fields.email.value = email
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: Только как в одной реакции использовать список параметров из UserStore?

Comment: Реакции придуманы для обновления UI, а не для связывания observable друг с другом.

Comment: тут посоветовали такой способ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46022157/mobx-getting-data-into-the-store-from-another-store